# How is the lower bound calculated for permutation of numbers in the backtracking algorithm?

Tags: permutations, algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

I was reading this for calculating permutation of numbers https://keaoxu.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/permutation_output_algo_analysis.pdf where a backtracking solution time complexity is presented.
Below is the algorithm from the paper
[image]

Below is the time complexity analysis
[image]

How is the lower bound calculated for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by showing sum of $x!$ where $x\le n$, is $\le e\cdot n!$ $\implies$ $$\begin{align}n \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \prod_{n-i}^{n} &= 
 n\cdot n! \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{n-i}^{n}\right)\\&=n\cdot n! \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-i-1)!}\\ &= n\cdot n! \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i!} \\&\le n\cdot n! \cdot e\\\\&=O(n\cdot n!)\end{align}$$